# Captcha broken when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: support, status-completed, captcha

**edit** new day, new luck... now it works fine (no JS required)

---

I tried https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha?s=3ee5d1b2-9656-4487-9804-80e2bccc0bc4 about ten times, but it's never accepted as correct:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hm, allowing recaptcha.net's JavaScript works then (although I'm getting an "oops" error because the edit is probably too old)